# Who are "we" in the pre-mortal life according to the LDS?

Tags: lds, doctrine-and-covenants

From this [link](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/new-era/2015/02/what-we-know-about-premortal-life?lang=eng)

> In our premortal life, **we** were taught lessons that prepared us to
> assist Heavenly Father in bringing about the salvation of His children
> (see D&C 138:56).

For a non Christian like me, especially English is not my mother language, it's difficult to understand a sentence which came from a Christian world.

That's why to me the word "we" in the quote is ambiguous since it can be:
A. We = the elects
B. We = all humankind

Hence the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B) all humankind

The next paragraph in the [article](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/new-era/2015/02/what-we-know-about-premortal-life?lang=eng) states

> The Prophet Joseph Smith explained that while in our premortal state, **we were all** present when God the Father explained His plan for the salvation of His children.

<sub>emphasis added by me</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the answer, depperm